# How do you define a typescript record where some of the keys have types and the others are freeform?

Tags: typescript

I want to have the types for some of the keys in the record to be strict, and the remainder to be freeform.

```
type Make "Volvo" | "Polestar" | "Saab";
interface Car {
    make: Make;
    horsePower: number;
    allWheelDrive: boolean;
    ...
}
```

and I want it accept

```
{
    make: "Saab",
    horsePower: 232,
    allWheelDrive: true,
    colour: "blue",
    trim: "leather
}
```

but not

```
{
   make: "Daimler",
   horsePower: 199,
   allWheelDrive: false,
   colour: "blue",
   trim: "leather
}
```

How do I write the `Car` interface to be able to do this with typescript?

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  Ideally someone could drop the code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/mbd4Ew) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  So there should be no typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values.

Comment: If I try to clear up your typos, [I don't see a problem](https://tsplay.dev/mAVM8W).  What specifically have you tried, and what goes wrong when you try it?  Can you spell it out?

Answer (score 0):

I think that enums would be the best for your purpose

```
enum Make {
    Volvo="Volvo",
    Polester="Polseter",
    Saab="Saab" 
}

interface Car {
    make: Make;
    horsePower: number;
    allWheelDrive: boolean;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to have "specialized" variants.

Each one of the variants has specific fields and types, and at the end there is a more "generic" one:

```
interface FooCar {
  make: 'foo';
  something: false;
  extraField: string;
}
interface BarCar {
  make: 'bar';
  something: true;
}
interface BazCar {
  make: 'baz';
  something: boolean;
  explosionProbability: number;
}

type Car =
  | FooCar
  | BarCar
  | BazCar
  | {
      make: string;
      something: boolean;
    };
```